# How to specify table for inserting data using peewee?

Tags: python, python-2.7, peewee

I use the following code to inserting data in DB:

```
db = dbConnection("localhost", "root", "")

class Products(peewee.Model):
    article = peewee.TextField()
    name = peewee.TextField()
    price = peewee.TextField()
    price_distributor = peewee.TextField()
    price_discount = peewee.TextField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

Products.create_table()
book = Products(article="1", name="2", price="3", price_distributor="4", price_discount="5")
book.save()
```

And connection function:

```
def dbConnection(host, user, password):
    return peewee.MySQLDatabase("test", host=host, port=3306, user=user, passwd=password)
```

How to set table name in which I insert data?

Comment: Take a look at the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709353/dynamically-define-name-of-class-in-peewee-model -- specifically the answer from @coleifer

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? 
when you save the product - the data is saved to the Products table, that's how you specify the table.

Comment: Really?  will it create table if not exsist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the docs on [peewee model options](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#model-options)

There is an option you can specify in `class Meta` called `db_table` which is the name of the table to store data.